# Vivaldi's address bar autoselects from my typed history

Tags: browser, vivaldi

I have been using Manjaro KDE for several years.  Lately, Firefox has been acting a bit unusual.  So I decided to give Vivaldi a try.

In Firefox's address bar, I can just type `youtube` <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and it goes to youtube home page.  I am not sure what this behaviour is called.  And I have no idea how Firefox does this, but it is a really neat feature.

In Vivaldi's address bar, when I type `youtube` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, it is selecting the first match from my (typed) history and starts to play a video.

Vivaldi's I've enabled setting/address-bar/domain expansion: and when I type `youtube` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then it goes to youtube home page.  But I had choose `com` as the domain, so not sure if it would work for other domains.  This is still very clunky, I have to type the entire thing `youtube` plus the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>; as oppose to `you` <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Is there a way I can make Vivaldi's address bar behave like Firefox's address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add youtube.com (or any other site where you want this to work) as a bookmark.
2. In Vivaldi's address bar settings (`vivaldi://settings/addressbar/`), make sure you have "Address Auto-Complete" set to enabled, and "Always Prefer Bookmarks" checked.

[image]

This should give you the behaviour you're after, i.e. when you start typing "you", it should allow you to auto-complete to your bookmark.

[image]